# Android to filter a list fragment with Filter API or CursorLoader

Tags: android, android-listview, filter, android-cursorloader

### Situation

I have data coming from a SQLite DataProvider on the phone. My fragment extends `ListFragment` and implements `LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>`. I am looking to have a `SearchView` widget to allow filtering of the ListView. In `onActivityCreated`, I am using `SimpleCursorAdapter` to find columns to my own xml layout. In `onCreateLoader`, I am using `CursorLoader`.

There are two approaches I can think of based on research.

#### Filter approach

I can get a filter from the adatper. My code:

```
Fragment frag = getView().findViewByTag(....);
Filter f = ((SimpleCursorAdapter) frag.getListView().getAdapter()).getFilter();
f.filter(<searchText>);
```

However the above code does nothing.

#### Re-launch loader with selection args

Relaunch the loader with right search texts, as stated [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/loaders.html#restarting)

```
Bundle args = new Bundle();
args.putString(SEARCH_TERM, text);
getLoaderManager().restartLoader(0, args, this);
```

Above seems to work.

The question is: is this by design that filter does not work with SimpleCursorAdapter? How should Filter interface be used?

It seems like I am just re-inventing the wheel of the Filter design.